# "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key...."

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, exception

for the past few days i keep on getting this error everytime i run a build in xCode:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x1dd4a1c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key playBtn.'
```

at the begining it was in something i have made. 
than i deleted it and it was still there - in an object (like this `playBtn` here) that did not exist anymore.

and now - in every single app i am trying to debug. 
if on my iphone or in the simulator - the same.

i just can't run anything now !!

*clean doesn't work ! *

what do i do? i can't work like this..

**notice:**
solved. it was a problem with the appdelegate.m 
thanks for who helped.

Comment: something is trying to access the @property review you `IBOutlet` connections.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key

Comment: @kirtimali saw it.. nothing helped...

Comment: @bit-whacker i did, nothing is wrong with it. also thing that used to work, untouched - makes the same error.

Comment: You wrote "and now - in every single app i am trying to debug."  Do you mean that for example if you create a new empty iPhone app and run it, you will still get this problem?

Comment: yes, in things that are not connected.
id don't get the error for the key of the other one, it is just that i get that error for some object i have in the new one.

Comment: I'm trying to identify whether this is an Xcode issue that you've identified, or if your xib files are incorrectly configured.  When you create a brand new project and run it immediately without making any changes whatsoever, do you still get this behavior?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added an exception breakpoint and copied the backtrace into your question.

Comment: [This](http://petosoft.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/key-value-horrors-and-nibxib-uiapplication-setvalueforundefinedkey-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-setvalueforundefinedkey-this-class-is-not-key-value/) may prove useful.

Comment: @EliranEfron: In that case, you should add your solution as an Answer and mark it as accepted instead of Editing the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

it was a problem with the appdelegate.m with the uitabbar.

thanks for who helped and those who tried :)

Answer (score 2):

Check your IBOutlet connections in your XIB

You said `playBtn` does not exists, so check if connection still exist for the same, They will show ! mark in place of dot in connections.

[image]

Comment: no no no, it does exsits in this project and it is connected correctly through *file's owner*

Comment: hmm just remove all connections in that.. may be that help you

Comment: tried to do that and launch it with no connections - same error

Answer (score 1):

I bet that You've got your File's Owner stuff messed up in your xibs.One of your views is set up to be the `playBtn` of the the File's Owner. However, when it's time to unarchive the nib, the owner doesn't have an `playBtn` property, so the unarchiving is failing.

**Two Things you can do :**

**1)** Check your **"Connections Inspector"** tab for the view that's throwing the error.
Remove all the Outlet Connections and re-connect all the Outlets.

**2)**

[image]

GoodLuck !!!

Comment: done that and it is still not working... can it be a problem with my xcode?

Comment: @EliranEfron: Ofcourse not. try to create simple application with some buttons and labels and check if it works or not.

Comment: ok i just made something and it worked but how do i fix it in my project?

Comment: all my old projects can't run ! even if they did before

Comment: @EliranEfron: If you are creating something new and it's working that means problem is not with your Xcode. Shocking to know that your Old Projects not working !!! In that case , you have to re-install your Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are indirectly (presumably when one of your nibs is unpacked) calling `-setValue:forKey:` on your `UIApplication`.

You can reproduce this issue by creating a new empty iPhone project and adding the following line to your app delegate's `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setValue:[[UIButton alloc] init] forKey:@"playBtn"];
```

Without a backtrace or even a complete log, it's hard to be sure, but it looks quite likely that you are having the same issue that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6294257/1052673).